# Sublime syntax log highlighting - multiline errors

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, logcat, sublime-syntax

I'm trying to create sublime syntax highlighting for android logs. Logs look something like this:

```
`2024-01-23 04:01:30,485 [pool-1-thread-39] DEBUG RootDo cmd=cat /sys/devices/soc0/soc/`
`2024-01-23 04:01:30,801 [pool-1-thread-5] INFO  AssetServerCommHandler send to link data:{"commId":"¸1","data":[{"classtype":"11","databoxid":1,"id":"fax","type":"1"}]`
`2024-01-23 04:01:33,332 [pool-1-thread-5] WARN  AssetServerCommHandler res={"resstatus":"NORMAL","statuses":["GET_DEPLOY"],"dataerrorids":[],"data":[{"classtype":"7","type":"7","ocode":null,"pcode":"CTB","regnum":"1"}],"load":1.0}`
`2024-01-23 04:01:33,334 [start_DCPServer] INFO  DCPShareUI onDrop /127.0.0.1`
```

These logs also include errors, than are in same format as the logs above, but they include stack trace under them.

```
2024-01-23 04:04:39,265 [dab] ERROR WebSocketConnector-asset onFailure
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=1: I/O error during system call, Software caused connection abort
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.read(NativeSsl.java:399)
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket$SSLInputStream.read(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:546)
    at okio.InputStreamSource.read(JvmOkio.kt:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

My problem is that with following syntax the first line after the error part does not register properly. (Time and thread are counted as ERROR, the rest of the line is nothing)
[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWjov.png)

```
%YAML 1.2
---
name: Log
file_extensions:
  - log

scope: source.log

contexts:
  main:
    - match: '\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} \[.*?\] ERROR .+)$'
      captures:
        1: keyword.log_level.ERROR
      push:
        - meta_scope: stack_trace
        - match: '^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} \[.*?\] (?!ERROR)'
          pop: true
    - match: '\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} \[.*?\] WARN .+)$'
      captures:
        1: keyword.log_level.WARN
    - match: '\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} \[.*?\] DEBUG .+)$'
      captures:
        1: keyword.log_level.DEBUG
    - match: '\b(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3} \[.*?\] INFO .+)$'
      captures:
        1: keyword.log_level.INFO
```